# Inline CSS in Joomla

Tags: css, joomla, inline

I am optimizing my site and I am following GTmetrix's suggestion to inline a small amount of css. Only I can't find where it is calling for this. I can see it when I view the source but when I check my different index.php files I can't seem to find where to make that edit. Any thoughts? Thanks. My site is www.destinychurchjacksonville.com and the css in question is:

http://www.destinychurchjacksonville.com/media/com_acymailing/css/module_default.css

Like I said, I can see where it calls for the file when viewing the source but my site is built in Joomla which is php.

Answer (score 1):

I've had really good results with [JCH Optimize](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/performance/jch-optimize). It's a moderately complex extension so plan on spending time reading the docs and testing the options.

It will combine multiple CSS and JS files and you have some options to inline the CSS.

If you can get most of the extension options working you'll be impressed with your grading improvements. For me, the big gains were from combining the multiple CSS and JS files.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The css file you are referring to is called from within other ccs files in the same folder located at /yourjoomlarootfolder/media/com_acymailing/css using:

```
@import url("module_default.css");
```

which seems to be called from mod_acymailing.php located at /yourjoomlarootfolder/modules/mod_acymailing depending on the acymailing skin/theme you are using

or at least that's what i found in a fast search i did on one of my sites using acymailing.